# Why does it keep saying TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscript-able when the predefined process is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def randomise_Chests_Bandits (sign,xSize,ySize,grid,pX,pY) :

    import random
    x = random.randint(0,xSize-1) #get a random x coordinate
    y = random.randint(0,ySize-1) #get a random y coordinate
    if (x == pX and y == pY) or (grid[x][y] != " "):
        grid = randomise_Chests_Bandits(sign,xSize,ySize,grid,pX,pY)
    else: 
        grid[x][y] = sign 
    return grid
```

It is called by : ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
for chestCount in range (0,chestCount): 
    grid = randomise_Chests_Bandits ('0',xSize,ySize,grid,pX,pY)
```

Why does it keep saying TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscript-able when the predefined process is called?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\AQA Game Final Coding With Help.py", line 271, in <module>
        Overall_Menu ()
    File "E:\AQA Game Final Coding With Help.py", line 264, in Overall_Menu
        grid = add_Chests_Bandits(grid,chestCount,banditCount,xSize,ySize,pX,pY)
    File "E:\AQA Game Final Coding With Help.py", line 223, inadd_Chests_Bandits
        grid = randomise_Chests_Bandits ('0',xSize,ySize,grid,pX,pY)
    File "E:\AQA Game Final Coding With Help.py", line 215, in randomise_Chests_Bandits
    if (x == pX and y == pY) or (grid[x][y] != " "):
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Can you add the *full traceback* for the exception, as well as your initial inputs? What is `grid` for example?

Comment: It looks like `grid` is a generator, but without the traceback I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: seems @francesco is right you might not initialize grid, thats why you get error.

Answer (score 0):

This is my interpretation of your question:

```
def randomise_Chests_Bandits (sign,xSize,ySize,grid,pX,pY) :

    import random
    x = random.randint(0,xSize-1) #get a random x coordinate
    y = random.randint(0,ySize-1) #get a random y coordinate
    if (x == pX and y == pY) or (grid[x][y] != " "):
        grid = randomise_Chests_Bandits(sign,xSize,ySize,grid,pX,pY)
    else:
        grid[x][y] = sign

    return grid


chestCount = 10
grid = [[" "]*20]*20
for chestCount in range (0,chestCount):
    grid = randomise_Chests_Bandits ('0',20,20,grid,10,10)

print(grid)
```

Maybe you forgot to initilized the array, this is the output:

```
[[' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' '], [' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '0', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', '0', ' ']]
```